# highchart - label color by based on point data

Tags: highcharts

I use highchart (spider chart).

I want the labels of xAxis to be colored dynamically, not immedient value.

I want to be able to write code like this:

```
let myConfig = {
    //...any config...
    options: {
       xAxis: {
         labels: {
           style: {
             color: function(point){
                 if (point.ext > 3){
                      return 'red';
                 }
                 else{
                      return 'green';
                 }
             }
           }
         }
       }
    }
```

Please don't suggest me do it by add labelStyle to each point; this way not named 'dynamic'.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`xAxis.labels.formatter`](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter)
Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/dtqx6wn0/

Points in a series will not be accessible (not created yet) at the time of the axis labels' formatter, but you could access raw data or processed x or y values of each series.